# Array defintion in Teradata Aggregate UDF

Tags: arrays, teradata, udf

I'm trying to create a Aggregate UDF function in teradata.

As a part of it im trying to decalre an array in intermediate storage.

It keeps on throwing the below error when im trying to link it to teradata.

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [7504 : HY000] in UDF/XSP/UDM DBC.IRR: SQLSTATE U0001: 
Elapsed time = 00:00:01.628 

STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.
```

Here is my code which im incorporating the array.

Is there any thing wrong with the syntax?

```
#include <sqltypes_td.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct agr_storage {
        FLOAT count;
        FLOAT val1,val2,val3,val4;
    FLOAT res[100]; // This is my array
} AGR_Storage;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Teradata limits each intermediate block size to 64 bytes and in the above code , we are trying to declare a array of size 800 bytes.

This is the reason for error.

Comment: The size of an *intermediate storage block* is limited to 64000 bytes and not 64 byte: http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1147_151K/C_UDFs.045.073.html